# What if today is Monday?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to do it with excel vba
If today is Monday, write "Today is Monday" in Label1. If not, hide the Label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place inside module.bas:

```
Function VBA_Weekday_Func(dDate as Date) as String
    Dim iWkDay As Integer      
    
    iWkDay = Weekday(dDate)
        
    If (iWkDay = vbMonday) Then
       VBA_Weekday_Func = "Today is Monday"
    Else
       VBA_Weekday_Func ="Today is not Monday"
    End If

End Function
```

In the cell enter: `=VBA_Weekday_Func(NOW())`